# Subharmonics frequency Vs Switching frequency

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

In current mode control of switching power supplies, it says that the subharmonics instability equals 1/2 of the switching frequency Ws, Can you please explain this fact?

Comment: A subharmonic is any fraction (more strictly, the reciprocal of any integer, i.e. a fraction with numerator 1) of the fundamental frequency. They are usually very minor in magnitude unless you're doing something very odd.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is about the frequency of these subharmonics, Why do we say that they are at half frequency of switching frequency of the power supply

Comment: Because that's the definition of a subharmonic; it's at half, or a third, or a fourth, etc., of the fundamental frequency.

Comment: Do you want to say, by applying fourier series for signals, we take the largest component (Half one)

Comment: The Switcher couples some parasitic charge into a control node of the feedback loop. The polarity of the charge gets reversed every cycle, thus TWO cycles are the parasitic-period.